# use of 'put together'

Tags: grammar

> He's got more wealth than that of Steve, John and Michelle put together.

I was wondering if an apostrophe 's' could be used in front of the names:

> He's got more wealth than that of Steve's, John's and Michelle's (wealth) put together.

Would it be a grammatically correct sentence ?

More Sentences

1. He's got more wealth than that of all of them put together. (not 'their's - right?)
2. He's got more wealth than that of all of us put together. (can't be us' right?)

Are the above sentences grammatically correct ?

Comment: We know you are talking about wealth so there is no need to repeat it. Also, the first one would be easier when spoken.

Answer (score 3):

The correct versions would be

> He's got more wealth than that of Steve, John and Michelle put together.

(as you said), and

> He's got more wealth than Steve's, John's and Michelle's put together.

but "that of Steve's, John's and Michelle's" is wrong — "that of" already indicates possessiveness so it is incorrect and redundant to add "'s" to indicate possessiveness.

The "than that of Steve, John, and Michelle" version sounds a little more natural to me but I don't have a technical reason to explain it.

Comment: You probably wouldn't even need the "that of."  "He's got more wealth than Steve, John, and Michelle put together," sounds more natural to my US English ear.

Comment: Yeah, I'd agree it sounds more natural, but it's grammatically incorrect: you would be comparing his wealth with 3 people put together (rather than their wealth), so it's not a proper parallel construction.

Comment: I had the same thought as I typed it.  I had an inner grammar vs conversation war and conversation won.  :)

Comment: Jason S - About my last sentence 'He's got more wealth than that of all of us put together.' Here can we use apostrphe for us as 'us's ?

Comment: "He's got more wealth than all of ours put together." Pronouns don't take apostrophe in their possessive form: I -> mine, you -> yours, he -> his, she -> hers, we -> ours, they -> theirs.